# Custom Errors in Fields, on Django

Tags: python, django

I have a custom signup app from views:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            userObj = form.cleaned_data
            username = userObj['username']
            email = userObj['email']
            password1 = userObj['password1']
            password2 = userObj['password2']
            if password1 != password2:
                return HttpResponse('password not match')
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                return HttpResponse('email must be unique')
            elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                return HttpResponse('username exists')

            else:
                user = form.save(commit=False)
                user.is_active = False
                user.save()
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                mail_subject = 'Activation'
                message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                    'user': user,
                    'domain': current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                })
                to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                email = EmailMessage(
                            mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
                )
                email.send()
                return HttpResponse('Letter is sent')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

This is the only way I made test for unique email working (models didn't work, dont know why).

*How can i make custom errors which i can put to my html using template tags {% if %}?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not tried using the [Django message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/).

**Look:**

**Adding a message**
To add a message, call:

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
```

Some shortcut methods provide a standard way to add messages with commonly used tags (which are usually represented as HTML classes for the message):

```
messages.debug(request, '%s SQL statements were executed.' % count)
messages.info(request, 'Three credits remain in your account.')
messages.success(request, 'Profile details updated.')
messages.warning(request, 'Your account expires in three days.')
messages.error(request, 'Document deleted.')
```

**Displaying messages**

```
get_messages(request)[source]
```

In your template, use something like:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

If you’re using the context processor, your template should be rendered with a RequestContext. Otherwise, ensure messages is available to the template context.

Even if you know there is only just one message, you should still iterate over the messages sequence, because otherwise the message storage will not be cleared for the next request.

The context processor also provides a DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS variable which is a mapping of the message level names to their numeric value:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
        {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}Important: {% endif %}
        {{ message }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

EDIT:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userObj = form.cleaned_data
            username = userObj['username']
            email = userObj['email']
            password1 = userObj['password1']
            password2 = userObj['password2']
            if password1 != password2:
                message = 'password not match'                
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                  message = 'email must be unique'
            elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                 message = 'email must be unique'
            messages.error(request, message)            
            else:
                user = form.save(commit=False)
                user.is_active = False
                user.save()
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                mail_subject = 'Activation'
                message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                    'user': user,
                    'domain': current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                })
                to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                email = EmailMessage(
                            mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
                )
                email.send()
                message = 'Letter was sent'
                messages.success(request, message)                 
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: What I return in my views.py using messages? I tried
User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
    return messages.error(request, 'trouble')
And I got error "The view accounts.views.signup didn't return an HttpResponse object".

Comment: Verify your installed apps in settings.py, there are django.contrib.messages.

Comment: I recommend you review this   step by step use of the message framework that is very good.  https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/09/06/django-tip-14-messages-framework.html. Maybe help you clarify your thougts. You need to render and send your request. Message only add your message to request dict, no more.

Comment: I have  'django.contrib.messages' there. I supose when i got case email.exists (my case) I need to render the same page (signup.html) using message additional. Am I right? If yes - how should I use this message and what should I return? Thanks!

Comment: You solve your problem? I think you have to post your solution here, or edit your question. Thanks.

Comment: In process right now. It works for email, but it does not work for password and username, I can get that error only via form.errors. Can you please give an advice how to turn off regular validation and I will edit my first post and will make the full instruction there. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162172/discussion-between-mayk-and-d-make).

Answer (score 0):

If we want to make a custom additional validation we can use messages. 
First of all add in views:

```
from django.contrib import messages
```

Then we just add terms of sending message to our HTML, for example:

```
if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.warning(request, 'email error.')
```

Now we can work with:

```
{% if messages %}
{% endif %}
```

In our HTML.

Also we can customise all our validations and ignore **is_valid** method.

Using:

```
from django.core import validators
```

we can use **validate_email** or **validate_slug** for fields we need.